# if statement in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am beginner in Javascript
I am always getting true returned whatever the values of my variables,
It should return true if a and b are both even, but false otherwise.
Thanks for your help.

https://repl.it/9nH/1675

```js
var a = 4;
var b= 5;
function areBothEqual (a, b) {
    if(a===b) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false
        
    }
}

var result = areBothEqual();
document.write(result)
```

Comment: if you don't pass in your defined values of a and b when you call the function, you are comparing null to null

Comment: Tip: `console.log(a, b)` inside your function.

Comment: Defining `(a,b)` as arguments to the function prevents your global vars being used in the function, as that is where you define what the function explicitly gets (global vars generally are to be avoided, so yay!) See other comments re: appropriate format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was obvious and I'm ashamed not having found this myself

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing the arguments to your function:

```
areBothEqual(a,b)
```

you had:

```
areBothEqual()
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are requesting the arguments `a` and `b` in the line `function areBothEqual (a, b)`, but they are never actually passed. Just replace the `(a, b)` with empty brackets `()`, as you can use the previously defined `a` and `b` instead.

```
var a = 4;
var b= 5;
function areBothEqual() {
    if(a===b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false

    }
}
areBothEqual()
```

Comment: Don't encourage the newbie to use global variables, teach him to pass arguments properly.

Comment: @Barmar one may want to use global variables if they always want to compare two particular values, but another answer highlights the alternative solution.

Comment: I'm not saying that global variables should never be used, but beginners use them too much because they don't understand functions. They should be used only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 4;
var b= 5;
function areBothEqual (a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    if(a===b) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false

    }
}
areBothEqual();
```

They are 'undefined' both are equals...

Comment: How does this fix the problem?

Comment: it isn't a problem.. It's telling you that they are equals. 'undefined' === 'undefined'

Comment: But he's clearly trying to compare the variables `a` and `b`. Show him how to do it correctly, don't just explain why his code doesn't work.